# 404 Can't find a route for 'get: home/test'

Tags: codeigniter-4

First of all, I am entirely new to this CI4, I have used CI3 in the past and had no issues. I installed CI4 using Composer, and everything was great. I have installed this new project in a folder name `rapti`. I tried accessing my site, it worked using this URL http://localhost/rapti/public/

Then to check I created a new function (`test`) in the default Controller `Home` and tried accessing the same with http://localhost/rapti/public/home/test but then I got an error:

> 404 Can't find a route for 'get: home/test'.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome_message');
    }
 
    public function test()
    {
        echo "This is Youtube";
    }
}
```

I tried creating another Controller `Youtube` and tried accessing that but no luck and the same error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Youtube extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "This is Youtube";
    }
}
```

If I try changing

```
public string $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

to

```
public string $uriProtocol = 'QUERY_STRING';
```

I do not get any error but everything redirects to default `Home` controller and `index` function, basically home page.

Comment: I am not sure it is your problem but it is where I would start - the `/public` dir is meant to be your DocumentRoot.  `/public` should not appear in your URL.  If you're [using Apache](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/running.html#virtual-hosting), that means `DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/public"`, if you're [using nginx](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/running.html#hosting-with-nginx) `root /path/to/your/public`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to route you webserver (apache or nginx) to the public folder inside your app. See @Don't Panic 's comment.

Furthermore you need to add the routes you are trying to access to the `route.php` file:

```php
$routes->get('home/test', 'Home::test');
$routes->get('youtube', 'Youtube::index');
```

Answer (score -1):

In the past, **CI3 had automatic routing by default**. Whereas in the latest version of **CI4**, `public bool $autoRoute = false;` which means that **automatic routing is not working**.

First of all, open the ***App/Config/Routing.php*** directory and look for the following code: `public bool $autoRoute = false;` and change it to `public bool $autoRoute = true;`

You also need to change `public string $defaultNamespace = 'App\Controllers';` to `public string $defaultNamespace = 'App\Controllers/';`

Now you can easily route to your CI4 application.